# Testing Abilities with Cancan when a token is involved

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, cancan

I am trying to figure out how to test an ability that allows a guest to view the results action of an AssessmentTake object if they have the related token.

Right now my test looks like:

```
describe Ability do
  subject { ability }
  let(:ability){ Ability.new(user) }

  describe "when user is a guest with the proper token" do
    let(:user) { nil }

    it { should be_able_to(:results, AssessmentTake) }
  end
end
```

Obviously, the problem with this is that it lets guest view results of any AssessmentTake without a token. The confusing aspect is that it feels like if I am going to test based on a token then I need to mock an AssessmentTake with a token?